# Can some explain where I would locate the start of this IDE controller register address map in memory?

Tags: x86, device-driver

I have been pouring through documentation as part of my quarter long project to develop a simple disk driver. At the moment I am trying to map out the various atapi and IDE controller registers implemented inside the Intel 82801EB IO controller.

First of all, the document I am referring to:
www.intel.com/assets/pdf/datasheet/252516.pdf

On page 415, table 154 shows the offsets of various configuration registers. This may seem like a silly question, but how do I find where they are offset *from*? I was expecting to find some sort of fixed base address reserved for these registers. From there I would be able to use this table build my driver.

For example, on table 154 the PCI command register is located at offsets 04-05h. The register is detailed on page 417, which I believe I am understanding. However, where is the base address that this register is located 4 bytes from?

Update:
Now, after looking back at the fixed IO map for the D865PERL board that we are using, it says that 0000-00ffh is reserved by the B865PERL, and to refer to the ICH5 data sheet for dynamic addressing information. Which I believe may be used for the IDE controller register from table 154 I mentioned above. At this point I emailed my professor but I am still trying to figure out where these are located.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I never had to find an actual address, but the bus/device/function number of the IDE controller.

1. enumerate through all possible PCI bus/device/function combinations searching for the vendor and device id of the IDE controller
2. once found, simply write the CONFIG_ADDRESS port, and read the info back from CONFIG_DATA

Basically, once you have a bus, device, and function (along with a register offset), you can write that info into the PCI CONFIG_ADDRESS register (cf8h) and read the register contents from CONFIG_DATA (cfch).

Answer (score 1):

Your 82801EB will be mapped to some address space in your hardware. This will be specific to your hardware, so you need to find the start address from your hardware manual.

```
Step-1: Get IEB_START_ADDRESS from you manual
For each of the registers in the IDE controller
Step-2: Add offset to IEB_START_ADDRESS (For example, if you want offset 04)
You will have to do dereference the address something like (*(IEB_START_ADDRESS + 4))
```

Now, beware of the register size.

If it is 16 bit use "unsigned short".

And if it is 32 bit use "unsigned int".

Comment: Ok, I am looking at the D865PERL motherboard manual and specifically the fixed IO address map.
download.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d865perl/sb/c3176401.pdf

In this fixed IO map (page 54) it lists addresses for the command block registers and such but I am unsure about the IDE controller registers. Would the table I mentioned in the op start at address 0000h-00ffh?

Comment: I assume you know the ATA protocol. As far as I understand from the the D865PERL specification, the Primary and Secondary IDE ports are mapped Command block : 0170-0177, 01f0 - 01f7. Also look at 0374 - 0377, 03f4 - 03f7 ...
I think You need not program the 82801EB controller directly.